# Which numbers whould you take for navigation priorization?

Tags: seo, google-analytics

If you should priorize the navigation links, what numbers whould you take as priorization basis:

- pageviews from GA,
- entrances from GA,
- revenue from GA,
- clicks from GSC,
- amount of top-10 rankings from GSC?

**PS**: it seems i'm bubble and the subject should be a bit more explained.

With priorization i mean the following procedure. You have an ecommerce site with some of ten thousands of categories and some hundreds of thousands of products. And your job is to select from all of this vivid diversity some categories and/or products to populate the main navigation menu.

In fact you can't put all categories and all products into this menu. Then rises the question: which numbers you take to select most important categories and products to link them in menu?

Comment: I'm not sure what "prioritze the navigation links" means here.   Are you trying to figure out which pages should receive optimized navigation links?  Are you trying to determine which pages should be included in navigation links?

Comment: Are you also going to consider hierarchy in your decisions?

Comment: @StephenOstermiller i added some details about the subject.

Answer (score 1):

Wow... thats a lot of categories!

But this is a nice mix you could go with:

1. The top level categories
2. Below the sub-categories with most demand (based on general demand and onpage demand)
3. Use some high converting categories
4. Use categories which need some more SEO boost to get more traffic and sales (as main navigation entries count as very important for searchengines). For example the categories which rank between 11 and 15 within a low/median competition.

If you have such a lot cats in your house, i guess you work with a "mega menu". So there is plenty of space and different columns to work with.

As always: Testing, analyzing, optimizing, and again.

Comment: well, like me too, no one seems to have a magic number, but works with the mix of metrics... I thought, i'm old school in the meanwhile, and there already exists a magic number:)